# Does a Locally Nilpotent Matrix Imply Nilpotent?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T:V \to V$ a linear operator. Prove that if $V$ is a Banach space, T is bounded and locally nilpotent, then $T$ is nilpotent.

I'm working on the above problem, but I'm stuck and I believe it's due to a misunderstanding of the definition of locally nilpotent. As I understand it, $T$ is locally nilpotent if $\forall \ v \in V \ \exists \ n$ such that $T^n(v)=0$. Then, if we assume $v'$ is an eigenvector of $T$, the following holds:
$$Tv'=\lambda v'$$
$$\Rightarrow T^2v'=\lambda^2v' $$
and this process continues until:
$$T^nv'=0=\lambda^nv' \iff \lambda =0$$
Doesn't this show that every locally nilpotent matrix is nilpotent? But I don't even use the fact that $V$ is a Banach space, or that $T$ is bounded. Moreover, the hint we were given tells us to use Baire category theorem, and I certainly haven't employed that.

So, I think I'm misunderstanding what it means to be locally nilpotent. Or is there something flawed in my provided work?

Comment: This isn't a proof that $T$ is nilpotent because you need a single $n$ such that $\forall v \in V~(T^n(v)=0)$.  You've just shown that for all $v \in V$ there is some $n$, which may depend on $v$, such that $T^n(v)=0$.

Comment: But haven't I shown that the eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$, which I thought was true if and only if $T$ was nilpotent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have shown that the only possible eigenvalue of $T$ is zero. But this does not imply that $T$ is nilpotent (in the **infinite-dimensional case**). To see this, consider the operator
$$T : \Bbb R^\infty \to \Bbb R^\infty$$
defined by
$$(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) \mapsto (a_2, a_3, \ldots).$$
($\Bbb R^\infty$ is the space of eventually zero sequences.)
Then, check that $T$ is locally nilpotent but not nilpotent.
Note that your proof does not really say that there is some uniform $n$ for which $T^n$ is zero. If it were the case that there is a basis of $V$ comprising of eigenvectors of $T$, then you could have concluded the desired result.

---

As a hint about how to actually solve the question: Define the closed sets $V_n$ as $\{v \in V : T^n v = 0\}$. Your hypothesis implies that the union of the $V_n$ is $V$. Baire's Category Theorem now implies that some $V_n$ has nonempty interior. Check now that $T^n \equiv 0$. (Note that if a vector subspace contains a ball around the origin, then it must be the whole space. Moreover, note that each $V_n$ is a vector subspace and thus, closed under translations. Use this to conclude that $V_n = V$.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I completed the proof but noticed that the assumption that $T$ is bounded is never used. Is this an unnecessary assumption? Or is that still necessary? It seems to me like it is a necessary condition for $T$ to be locally nilpotent, but once that assumption is given, we no longer need to assume $T$ is bounded.

Comment: @TyPerkins: $T$ being bounded is equivalent to $T$ being continuous, which is equivalent to kernel of $T$ being closed. Note that the $V_n$s I defined are the precisely the kernels of $T^n$. Thus, $V_n$ is closed iff $T^n$ is continuous (iff $T^n$ is bounded).

Comment: Note that you can't apply BCT otherwise. For example, $\Bbb R = \Bbb Q \cup \Bbb Q^c$ is the the union of two subspaces with empty interiors.